# kivy multiple instances of a screen with unique data

Tags: python, kivy

good day

is it possible to have multiple instances of a screen each using unique data? for example, i have a 'homescreen' with various buttons for various categories that takes you to a batch list screen unique to that category where you can add batches to be listed. each buttons batch list screen would have unique data to that category but the template for all batch list screens are the same.

ive made a simple example for one category but in order to expand it to the others would i need to repeat the code and create appropriately named .kv files and add each screen to the screen manager.

**.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple import TouchRippleButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class CapitalInput(TextInput):

    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        s = substring.upper()
        return super(CapitalInput, self).insert_text(s, from_undo=from_undo)


class RippleButton(TouchRippleButtonBehavior, Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point:
            touch.grab(self)
            self.transparency = self.background_color[3]
            self.background_color[3] = 0.5  # set transparency to half (0.5)
            self.ripple_show(touch)
            self.dispatch('on_press')
            return True
        return False

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self.ripple_fade()

            def defer_release(dt):
                self.background_color[3] = self.transparency
                self.dispatch('on_release')

            Clock.schedule_once(defer_release, self.ripple_duration_out)
            return True
        return False


class AddBatchScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BatchScreen(Screen):
    pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


gui = Builder.load_file('BatchTracker.kv')


class BatchTrackerApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return gui

    def insert(self, value):
        bs = self.root.get_screen('batch_screen')
        bs.ids.rv.data.insert(0, {'value': value or 'default value'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BatchTrackerApp().run()
```

**BatchTraker.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:include batchscreen.kv
#:include add_batch_screen.kv
#:include homescreen.kv
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import TouchRippleButtonBehavior kivy.uix.behaviors.touchripple
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition


ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    HomeScreen:
        name: 'home_screen'
        id: home_screen

    BatchScreen:
        name: 'batch_screen'
        id: batch_screen

    AddBatchScreen:
        name: 'add_batch_screen'
        id: add_batch_screen


<RoundButton@RippleButton>:
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color: (1,0,1,1)
    border_radius: [20]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
```

**homescreen.kv**

```
<HomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 0.7, 0.5, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            size_hint_y: None
            pos_hint: {'top': .1}
            text: 'Home Screen'
            font_size: 40

        GridLayout:
            rows: 4

            AnchorLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.9
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 0.7
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'
                    text: 'Isolations'
                    font_size: 40
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    on_press: print('isolations')
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'batch_screen'

            AnchorLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.9
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 0.7
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'
                    text: 'QPCR'
                    font_size: 40
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text_size: self.width, None
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'batch_screen'

            AnchorLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.9
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 0.7
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'
                    text: 'PCR'
                    font_size: 40
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text_size: self.width, None

            AnchorLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.9
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
                    size_hint: 0.5, 0.7
                    halign: 'center'
                    valign: 'middle'
                    text: 'Electrophoresis'
                    font_size: 40
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text_size: self.width, None
```

**batchscreen.kv**

```
<Row@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Button:
        text: root.value
        font_size: sp(80)
        on_press: print(f'pressed button {root.value}')

<BatchScreen>:
    rv: rv #to expose the widget
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('c6e2ff')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        FloatLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('b3b3ff')
                RoundedRectangle:
                    radius: 0,0,25,25
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            pos_hint: {'top':1}
            size_hint: 1, .1

            Label:
                id: lb
                text: 'User'
                font_size: 60
                pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'x': .15}
                size_hint: .2, .8

            RoundButton:
                text: 'Sign Out'
                font_size: 40
                on_release: print('Sign Out pressed')
                pos_hint: {'top': .95, 'x': .55}
                size_hint: .4, .8

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('eaec3c')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
            size_hint: 0.9,0.8

            RecycleView:
                id: rv
                viewclass: 'Row'
                scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
                scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
                bar_width: dp(10)
                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    default_size: None,100
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'


        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('969c9c')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            pos_hint: {'y': 0}
            size_hint: 1, .1

            RoundButton:
                id: add_batch
                text: 'Add Batch'
                font_size: 30
                on_press: root.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="left")
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'add_batch_screen'
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'x': .05}
                size_hint: .4, .8
                back_color: hex('62fd00')

            RoundButton:
                text: 'Remove Batch'
                font_size: 30
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                size: self.texture_size
                text_size: self.width, None
                on_release: print('Remove pressed')
                on_release: print(root.manager.ids.batch_screen.rv.data)
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'x': .55}
                size_hint: .4, .8
                back_color: hex('fd0000')

            RoundButton:
                text: 'Back'
                font_size: 30
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'
                size: self.texture_size
                text_size: self.width, None
                on_press: print('Back pressed')
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'home_screen'
                pos_hint: {'center_y': .5, 'x': .55}
                size_hint: .4, .8
                back_color: hex('0000ff')
```

**add_batch_screen.kv**

```
<AddBatchScreen>:
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 0,0,1,1
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size

CapitalInput:
    id: capital_input
    size_hint: .9, .15
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .6}
    font_size: 40
    padding: [0, (self.height-self.line_height)/2]
    hint_text: 'Batch No.'
    multiline: False
    halign: 'center'   


Button:
    id: addbtn
    text: 'Add'
    size_hint: .4, .08
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .2}
    on_press: app.insert(capital_input.text) if capital_input.text != '' else None
    on_release: capital_input.text = ''

Button:
    text: 'Batch List'
    size_hint: .4, .08
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .1}
    on_press: root.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction="right")
    on_release: root.manager.current = 'batch_screen'
    on_release: print(root.manager.ids.batch_screen.rv.data)
```

Comment: ps. forgive the colours, they more of a visual aid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a lot of code you will have a hard time finding someone to give you a specific answer. Without looking through all of your code, yes it is possible to have multiple instances of a screen with unique data. This is exactly the use case of class instances. You simply need to pass a variable, list or object into the instance. I will give you a short example, then you should be able to figure it out yourself for your code.

```
class MyReusableScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        super(MyReusableScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = data
        mylabel = Label(text=self.data['mylabel_text'])
```

We added the attribute data to the class. Now we have to pass the data when we initialize the class instance

```
data1 = {'mylabel_text': 'first label'}
data2 = {'mylabel_text': 'second label'}

screen1 = MyReusableScreen(data=data1)
screen2 = MyReusableScreen(data=data2)
```

Like this we added unique label texts to the class instances labels. I guess you should now be able to build it up on your own. In case you defined a label in kv language, give it an id like for exanple `id: mylabel` and then assign the data value like this within you screen `mylabel.text = self.data['mylabel_text']`. I hope this helps you and if you struggle with something just give me a sign.

Comment: if i in instantiate screen 1 and 2 in the .kv file under a screenmanager widget, how would i pass the attribute data to it? currently i've managed to create the two instances of the reusable screen, but they seem to share the same recycleview data set. any guidance appreciated. thanks.